# Why the method is not called -- jRuby Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, nomethoderror

I have this Java class

```
class Dog {
  private String name;

  public Dog() {
    name = "Fido";
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

And as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917358/jruby-on-rails-using-custom-java-classes-in-your-rails-app/3917676#3917676) I have performed these steps

```
1. Compile the class.
      mkdir classes
      javac -d classes src/Dog.java

   2.Add classes to the classpath in your Rails application (an initializer for example).
      require 'java'
      $CLASSPATH << File.join(Rails.root, "classes")

   3.Import the class.
      java_import Java::Dog
```

But still I am not able to access the `getName()` method in rails 3 with the `NoMethodError`, but the method is accesible in jRuby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making the java class PUBLIC it worked for me.since the default is package-private